# Imaginary woman brought to life at the end

Tags: story-identification

I remember seeing a movie about a guy, possibly a scientist, who can see and talk to a beautiful woman who appears to be somewhat imaginary and sometimes invisible. He has to stop some rival scientist from approving a launch and at the end of the movie, he uses some kind of stone--probably from space--to bring this woman to life and make her a real woman in the end. What is the name of this movie?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  If you can remember any more details (such as when you saw it, when it came out, etc.) please put them in!

Comment: Uh, spoilers! :P